# pandas apply and assign to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with column like:

```
col 
a2_3
f4_4
c4_1
```

I want to add two columns from this column, 
like so:

```
col   col1   col2   col3
a2_3    a      2     3
f4_4    f      4     4
c4_1    c      4     1
```

The following does not work:

```
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']] = df['col'].apply(lambda s: (s[1], *s[1:].split("_")) )
```

How can I assign series of tuples to new columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `apply` is not necessary, first indexing with `str` and then use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True`:

```
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df['col'].str[1:].str.split("_", expand=True)
print (df)
    col col1 col2
0  a2_3    2    3
1  f4_4    4    4
2  c4_1    4    1
```

Your solution is possible with `Series` constructor, but it is slow:

```
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df['col'].apply(lambda s: pd.Series(s[1:].split("_")))
```

Faster is use DataFrame constructor:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['col'].apply(lambda s: s[1:].split("_")).tolist(), index=df.index)
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df1
```

Or list comprehension:

```
df[['col1', 'col2']] = pd.DataFrame([s[1:].split("_") for s in df['col']], index=df.index)
```

EDIT: Solution is similar:

```
L = df['col'].apply(lambda s: (s[0], *s[1:].split("_"))).tolist()
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']] = pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index)

df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']] = pd.DataFrame([(s[0], *s[1:].split("_")) for s in df['col']], 
                                 index=df.index)
print (df)
    col col1 col2 col3
0  a2_3    a    2    3
1  f4_4    f    4    4
2  c4_1    c    4    1
```

Comment: wrapping in pd.Series is VERY slow. (100K rows), without pd.Series it is fairly fast. Is there a way to make it faster and still use apply?

Comment: Edited the question, I need the first letter as well as a third column